# How to make clickable <tr> accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a table where every `<tr>` opens the `<tr>` below it.
How can I make it accessible to the user
so that they can know the `<tr>` is clickable and will open the `<tr>` below it?

Example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>bla1</th>
            <th>bla2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="infoBlock" data-id="t1">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detailsBlock" data-id="t1">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="infoBlock" data-id="t2">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="detailsBlock" data-id="t2">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The user (who uses a screen reader) needs to know that when they click

```
<tr class="infoBlock" data-id="t1">
```

it opens

```
<tr class="detailsBlock" data-id="t1">
```

I know that the `aria-expanded` attribute can be used on `<button>` and `<a>`.
https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_the_WAI-ARIA_aria-expanded_state_to_mark_expandable_and_collapsible_regions

Comment: You are using a data table for layout purpose This would be laboriously accessible.

Comment: A table is most likely a poor fit for this. What does the text/data that is intended to populate that look like?

Answer (score -4):

You can use the [data- attribute](https://codepen.io/natureboy153/pen/WRgbQK) on table row.

```
<tr tabindex="0" role=button data-bind="click: SelectOnClick, event: {keypress: SelectOnKeyup}">
```

Comment: What solution? Am I missing something?